# Rails 3 migration - what is the equivalent of this route in the new world

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
map.resource :account, :controller => "users"
```

That is, how do I map the resource account to the users controller?

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as before, as stated [there in the RailsGuides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use). You may want to make your resource plural though (assuming you have several accounts, it makes some sense, but after all it depends on the actual meaning you give it).

Comment: Its the current user account, so I will stick with singular, thanks for the document reference.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as before but without `map.`:

```
resource :account, :controller => "users"
```